# When migrating on premises database to sql azure database it ignores DEFAULT (newid()) in all Table creation scripts

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, uniqueidentifier, azure-sql-database

I have migrated an on premises database to sql azure database using SQLAzureMW v5.16 for sql server 2014 . before migrating it gave me scripts that would execute in my SQL Azure database. and it did containg newid() in table creation script as can be seen as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AUDITLOG](
[CUSTOMERID] [decimal](38, 0) NULL,
[RRNVALUE] [varchar](12) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[TRANSACTIONCODE] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ACTIONID] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[MODULEID] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[CNIC] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ACTIVITYDATE] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ACTIVITYTIME] [varchar](6) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ACTIVITYDETAILS] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[RESPONSECODE] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[SESSIONID] [varchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[BASECUSTOMERID] [decimal](38, 0) NULL,
[SOURCE] [varchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[LOGID] [decimal](38, 0) NULL,
[AGENT] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD1] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD2] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD3] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD4] [varchar](4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[USERIP] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[LOGGINGNATURE] [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[LOGINID] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ROWID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid())
```

)

```
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ROWID$INDEX] ON [dbo].[AUDITLOG]
(
    [ROWID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)
GO
```

after successful migration it was seen that constraint DEFAULT (newid()) was removed in all table creation scripts. and following was produced:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AUDITLOG](
[CUSTOMERID] [decimal](38, 0) NULL,
[RRNVALUE] [varchar](12) NULL,
[TRANSACTIONCODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ACTIONID] [varchar](15) NULL,
[MODULEID] [varchar](20) NULL,
[CNIC] [varchar](15) NULL,
[ACTIVITYDATE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[ACTIVITYTIME] [varchar](6) NULL,
[ACTIVITYDETAILS] [varchar](4000) NULL,
[RESPONSECODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[SESSIONID] [varchar](30) NULL,
[BASECUSTOMERID] [decimal](38, 0) NULL,
[SOURCE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LOGID] [decimal](38, 0) NULL,
[AGENT] [varchar](4000) NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD1] [varchar](4000) NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD2] [varchar](4000) NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD3] [varchar](4000) NULL,
[RESERVEDFIELD4] [varchar](4000) NULL,
[USERIP] [varchar](15) NULL,
[LOGGINGNATURE] [varchar](100) NULL,
[LOGINID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ROWID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
```

)

GO

is there a reason newid() is removed when migrating tables from on premises to Azure cloud?? ..

Comment: which version of azure you are using

Comment: @TheGameiswar Azure database V12

Comment: I think you've found a limitation of the migration wizard.  Manually scripting your table to Azure worked for me. You may want to import your schema into SSDT, then deploy your changes to Windows Azure SQL Database.  You'll get better control over what is deployed to the target database, and you can tweak your design. Setting a clustered index on a unique identifier is going to cause you performance issues on premise or in the cloud my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think default newid() is available in sql azure, but its available in azure sql datawarehouse

Please check msdn link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: I just ran a manual create table with a rowID column like the OP had. I then ran an insert statement, select statement verified I got a guid, and dropped the table all successfully.  NEWID() is valid in Windows Azure SQL Database V12.